# Automatisation of correlations testing of linear model residuals

Tags: r, correlation, anova

Is there a method/code available to automate the correlation testing procedure i am using? The automatisation code should enable the comparison of all columns within a dataset and also generate a correlation matrix as output. For now, i am manually changing the column names within the code and writing the result on an Excel sheet. However, as there are more than 60 observation columns this is laborious, hence the question.

Detailed reasons for this approach to correlation analysis can be found [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/04/dealing-with-correlation-in-designed-field-experiments-part-i/).

I prepared a code example using an IRIS dataset. The IRIS dataset originally doesn't contain replications, however, 50 replications per observation and species are available. The code is the same as I'm using for the analysis of my data set.

```
mm1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ factor(Replication) + Species, data=iris)
res1 <- mm1$residuals
mm2 <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ factor(Replication) + Species, data=iris)
res2 <- mm2$residuals
cor.test(res1,res2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ignoring your `Replication` because you didn't provide data containing it. However, the following should be easy to adjust.

```
DF <- iris

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DFlong <- melt(DF, id.vars = "Species")

library(nlme)
mm <- lmList(value ~ Species | variable, data = DFlong, na.action = na.fail)

res <- matrix(residuals(mm), nrow = nrow(DF), dimnames = list(NULL, rownames(coef(mm))))

library(psych)
cors <- corr.test(res)

print(cors, digits = 2, short = FALSE)
# Call:corr.test(x = res)
# Correlation matrix 
#              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# Sepal.Length         1.00        0.53         0.76        0.36
# Sepal.Width          0.53        1.00         0.38        0.47
# Petal.Length         0.76        0.38         1.00        0.48
# Petal.Width          0.36        0.47         0.48        1.00
# Sample Size 
# [1] 150
# Probability values (Entries above the diagonal are adjusted for multiple tests.) 
#              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# Sepal.Length            0           0            0           0
# Sepal.Width             0           0            0           0
# Petal.Length            0           0            0           0
# Petal.Width             0           0            0           0
# 
#  Confidence intervals based upon normal theory.  To get bootstrapped values, try cor.ci
#             raw.lower raw.r raw.upper raw.p lower.adj upper.adj
# Spl.L-Spl.W      0.40  0.53      0.64     0      0.36      0.67
# Spl.L-Ptl.L      0.68  0.76      0.82     0      0.65      0.84
# Spl.L-Ptl.W      0.22  0.36      0.50     0      0.22      0.50
# Spl.W-Ptl.L      0.23  0.38      0.51     0      0.21      0.52
# Spl.W-Ptl.W      0.34  0.47      0.59     0      0.30      0.61
# Ptl.L-Ptl.W      0.35  0.48      0.60     0      0.31      0.63

cors$r
#             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#Sepal.Length    1.0000000   0.5302358    0.7561642   0.3645064
#Sepal.Width     0.5302358   1.0000000    0.3779162   0.4705346
#Petal.Length    0.7561642   0.3779162    1.0000000   0.4844589
#Petal.Width     0.3645064   0.4705346    0.4844589   1.0000000

cors$p
#             Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
#Sepal.Length 0.000000e+00 1.495184e-11 2.860911e-28 4.524678e-06
#Sepal.Width  2.990368e-12 0.000000e+00 3.724687e-06 3.699152e-09
#Petal.Length 4.768185e-29 1.862343e-06 0.000000e+00 1.340992e-09
#Petal.Width  4.524678e-06 1.233051e-09 3.352479e-10 0.000000e+00

cors$p.adj
#[1] 1.495184e-11 2.860911e-28 3.724687e-06 4.524678e-06 3.699152e-09 1.340992e-09
```

You should use the adjusted p-values (i.e., the upper triangle of the `cors$p` matrix) if you do more than one comparison.

Comment: Many thanks. Could you explain how to update the melt function to include the BLOCK as the id column? Currently, BLOCK is added to the Variable column, and the block number to the values column.

Comment: `id.vars = c("Species", "Block")`